# Outer div now displaying the background all the way to the bottm

Tags: html, css

I have this page:

http://www.comehike.com/community/search_hikers.php

It has a div on the right side that contains a column.  The blue background doesn't go low enough and makes the bottom of the right side look broken.

Here are the styles for that div:

```
#rightbar_200 {
margin-top: 10px; 
min-height: 412px; 
padding: 0 10px; 
width:202px; 
border: 0; 
background: #4C7AAB;
}

#rightbar_200 li {
margin:5px;
list-style: none outside none;
}

#rightbar_200 li a{
font-size: 1.2em;

}

#rightbar_200 ul {
margin:0;
}

#rightbar_200 .chapter {
padding-left: 0;
}
#rightbar_200 .chapter .chapter_title {
font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

Any idea why the blue background does not extend further down?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adjusting #rightbar_200 min-height to 452px?

Comment: Why do you think it is min-height?  Is min-height controlling the overall height in this case?

Comment: It worked, but not sure why it is the min-element that controls the max of the height :)

Comment: The min-height doesn't control the max. It controls the min, as in 'it should be at least 452px, but bigger if need be.'

Comment: Personally, I would leave that the way you have it. I am assuming "Hiking articles" content changes, making the height change. The content is what's going to rule here. Maps, etc. I made the adjustment with the min-height I gave you, and it expanded the blue